# data not reaching overridden ToString() method

Tags: c#

I have an overridden `ToString()` method that I want to output formatted data. This data consisted of 11 different items.  I can get all but one item to display properly but that one item just shows up as 0.  Somehow, it is not reaching the `ToString()` method.  I debugged the program and followed the data line by line and it disappears at the point right before going to the `ToString()` method and I have no idea why.  Here is my code.  I'm only posting the code I think is involved with passing the data.  If I am wrong and all of the code is needed, let me know.

```
private void btnPaymentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        amountPaid = double.Parse(this.txtAmountPaid.Text);

        orderPaymentObject = new Payment(orderObject.TotalAmountDue, amountPaid);            

        this.txtNumberOfPizzaOrdered.Clear();
        this.txtNumberOfCokesOrdered.Clear();
        this.txtAmountDue.Clear();
        this.txtAmountPaid.Clear();

        this.lblYourOrder.Visible = true;
        this.rtxtYourOrder.Visible = true;

        this.rtxtYourOrder.Text =  orderObject.ToString();               
    }     

.......

public class Payment
{
    PizzaOrder orderObject;
    double amountPaid = 0.0,
            totalAmountDue = 0.0;        

    public Payment()
    {
    }

    public Payment(double amountDue, double payment)
    {  
        orderObject = new PizzaOrder();
        amountPaid = payment;
        totalAmountDue = amountDue;
        orderObject.GetChangeDue(totalAmountDue, amountPaid);
        //orderObject.ToString();            
    }

    public Payment(double payment)
    {
        amountPaid = payment;
    }

    public double AmountPaid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.amountPaid;
        }
    }
}

......

public override string ToString()
    {
        Payment paymentOrder = new Payment();

        return string.Format(" {0} Pizzas @ {1:C}: {2,8:C}\n" +
            " {3} Cokes @ {4:C}:  {5,8:C}\n" +
            "       Order Amount: {6,8:C}\n" +
            "             Sales Tax: {7,9:C}\n" +
            "         Amount Due: {8,8:C}\n" +
            "         Amount Paid: {9,9:C}\n\n" +
            "              Change Due: {10,9:C}", NumberOfPizzas, 
            PIZZA_PRICE, totalCostOfPizza, NumberOfCokes, COKE_PRICE,
            totalCostOfCoke, FoodAndDrinkTotal, TotalSalesTax, 
            TotalAmountDue, paymentOrder.AmountPaid, GetChangeDue(totalAmountDue,amountPaid));
    }
```

The value that is not being passed is the `amountPaid` (second from last).

I've tried:

- passing the `amountPaid` variable in the `OrderFrom` class by instantiating an `OrderForm` object both inside and outside of the `ToString()` method,
- passing the `amountPaid` variable in the `Payment` class by instantiating a `Payment` object both inside and outside of the `ToString` method, and
- calling inputting the `amountPaid` variable in the `toString` method as a variable and as a property.

To be honest I've grasped at so many straws that I am now completely confused and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be? You instantiate a `new Payment` inside the overridden method with no parameters (thus a 0 for AmountPaid). What would give you an expectation that there would be anything other than 0 here?

Comment: I've tried it both with and without the amountPaid parameter.  I just tried it again, still gets a zero.  When I debug it, the data disappears when it leaves "this.rtxtYourOrder.Text =  orderObject.ToString();" and goes to the ToString() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ToString` provides wrong payment info because it, quite honestly, does not have access to that payment object that you are creating. Instantiating `new Payment` does not help: you need a different approach here.

One way to deal with the problem is to make a `FormatWithPayment` method, instead of overriding `ToString`. It is a good idea to avoid using the plain `ToString` in your business code, reserving it to debugging and logging.

```
public string FormatWithPayment(Payment paymentOrder )
{
    return string.Format(" {0} Pizzas @ {1:C}: {2,8:C}\n" +
        " {3} Cokes @ {4:C}:  {5,8:C}\n" +
        "       Order Amount: {6,8:C}\n" +
        "             Sales Tax: {7,9:C}\n" +
        "         Amount Due: {8,8:C}\n" +
        "         Amount Paid: {9,9:C}\n\n" +
        "              Change Due: {10,9:C}"
        ,   NumberOfPizzas
        ,   PIZZA_PRICE
        ,   totalCostOfPizza
        ,   NumberOfCokes
        ,   COKE_PRICE
        ,   totalCostOfCoke
        ,   FoodAndDrinkTotal
        ,   TotalSalesTax
        ,   TotalAmountDue
        ,   paymentOrder.AmountPaid
        ,   GetChangeDue(totalAmountDue,amountPaid)
        );
}
```

It's almost the same as your code, only the payment object is now passed in.

Now you can modify your click handler to use this new method, like this:

```
this.rtxtYourOrder.Text =  orderObject.FormatWithPayment(orderPaymentObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code shows the `ToString()` override *outside* the Payment class.  If that's a true representation of your actual code, then you have overridden `ToString()` on some class other than `Payment`.  This analysis is supported by your instantiation of a `new Payment` object inside the method.

The `ToString()` method is an instance method.  It should return a string representation *of the instance on which it is called.*  If you're trying to get a string representation of a `Payment`, the method should be an instance method of the `Payment` class, and it should get its values from the instance properties (and possibly instance fields) of that class.

Make the method a member of the `Payment` class, and use `this.` rather than `paymentOrder.`; this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I see is that your architecture is off. You have a `PizzaOrder` as a "sort of" member of the `Payment` class, and your `ToString()` method is a member of (I assume) the `PizzaOrder` class. Rather than building formatting methods to handle all of this, you should relate your objects appropriately.

A pizza order should have a payment associated with it so you should have a class structure similar to:

```
public class PizzaOrder
{

    ...

    public Payment PaymentInfo { get; set; }

    // then have your method:
    // What ToString() method are you overriding?
    // Does the baseclass for a pizza order already
    // have a ToString()?
    public override string ToString()
    {
        double paymentAmount = 0;

        if (this.PaymentInfo != null)
            paymentAmount = this.PaymentInfo.AmountPaid;

        return string.Format(" {0} Pizzas @ {1:C}: {2,8:C}\n" +
            " {3} Cokes @ {4:C}:  {5,8:C}\n" +
            "       Order Amount: {6,8:C}\n" +
            "             Sales Tax: {7,9:C}\n" +
            "         Amount Due: {8,8:C}\n" +
            "         Amount Paid: {9,9:C}\n\n" +
            "              Change Due: {10,9:C}", NumberOfPizzas, 
            PIZZA_PRICE, totalCostOfPizza, NumberOfCokes, COKE_PRICE,
            totalCostOfCoke, FoodAndDrinkTotal, TotalSalesTax, 
            TotalAmountDue, paymentAmount,
            GetChangeDue(totalAmountDue, paymentAmount));
    }     

}
```

I think you need to revisit your architecture a little more thoroughly and establish stronger relationships between your classes.

Comment: Could you please explain the public Payment PaymentInfo { get; set }? It looks like a property but what is PaymentInfo?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie: That would just be the name of the property. You have to get to it somehow, and since that object contains payment information it seemed sensible. The idea behind it is simply to connect payment information directly to a pizza order through a parent-child relationship.